# Python Applying a CDF after Fitter

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy, scipy.stats

I would like to apply the best fit CDF found by Fitter to each value in a number of panda data-frame columns by hopefully passing the Fitter results to Scipy Stats (or another library?).

I can get the distribution function easily enough from Fitter with the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from fitter import Fitter
from fitter import get_common_distributions

from fitter import get_distributions

dataset = pd.read_csv("econ.csv")
dataset.head()

sns.set_style('white')
sns.set_context("paper", font_scale = 2)

sns.displot(data = dataset, x = "Value_1",kind = "hist", bins = 100, aspect = 1.5)

spac = dataset['Value_1'].values
f = Fitter(spac, distributions=get_distributions())

f.fit()
f.summary()

f.get_best(method='sumsquare_error')
```

This provides me with an output for Value_1:

{'norminvgauss': {'a': 1.87,
'b': -0.65,
'loc': 0.46,
'scale': 1.24}}

Now this is where I am stuck:

Is there a way to pass this information back to Scipy Stats (or another library) so I can calculate the cumulative distribution function (CDF) of the best fit for each value in each column?

The dataset columns range from Value_1 to Value_99 with about 400 rows - Once I know how to feed the fitter results back into scipy stats I should be able to write a simple for loop to apply this over each column.

An example of the result would be like:

| ID | Value1 | CDF_BestFit_Value1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| n | 0.9 | 0.33 |
| n+1 | 0.7 | 0.07 |

Much appreciated in advanced for anyone who is able to help with this.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? @MikalFischer

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to pass this information back to Scipy Stats (or another library) so I can calculate the cumulative distribution function (CDF) of the best fit for each value in each column?

IIUC, the information you are trying to pass back to `scipy.stats` is like

```py
{'norminvgauss': {'a': 1.87, 'b': -0.65, 'loc': 0.46, 'scale': 1.24}}
```

In this example, you would want to evaluate the CDF of the `norminvgauss` distribution with these parameters. The difficulty is that you want to do this programatically given the name of the distribution family as a string and the parameter name/value pairs as a dictionary.

One way to extract the name of the distribution family and the parameter info is like:

```py
dist_name, params = list(d.items())[0]
```

(Perhaps there are more elegant ways, but this is the first that comes to mind. It's unusual to have just single key in the dictionary, but I often iterate over dictionaries like `for dist_name, params in d.items()`.)

Then, the way to get the distribution family object is:

```py
dist_family = getattr(stats, dist_name)
```

I would pass the parameters to the distribution family object to create a "frozen" distribution with those parameters:

```py
dist = dist_family(**params)
```

and then you can evaluate its `cdf` at whatever arguments you please.

```py
dist.cdf([0, 0.5, 1])
```

For easier copy-pasting:

```py
from scipy import stats
d = {'norminvgauss': {'a': 1.87, 'b': -0.65, 'loc': 0.46, 'scale': 1.24}}

dist_name, params = list(d.items())[0]
dist_family = getattr(stats, dist_name)
dist = dist_family(**params)
dist.cdf([0, 0.5, 1])
# array([0.45497638, 0.69433145, 0.87312848])
```

The rest - extracting the arguments from the dataframe and writing the results to the dataframe - is just `pandas`, and it sounds like you have that under control.